# Identify an SF short - humanity alone in universe.

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I could have sworn this story was by James White, but I can't ID it if it is.

Basic premise, story opens with a guy waiting for a starship to arrive.  It had been sent out decades before as part of a search to track down an alien race that had left traces on an extra-solar planet.  This was the only race we had found evidence of.  All other ships had returned with no success.  This ship was the last.  Ship comes in, crew exits.  They either didn't find anything or they found the other race's home planet and they were extinct.  (Don't remember.)  Humanity is alone in the universe.

Only distinctive element I recall is one of the crew had memorized the Bible during the round trip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"['The Years Draw Nigh'](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69134)", a short story by [Lester del Rey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lester_del_Rey), first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, October 1951](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57650+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v48n02_1951-10_Gorgon776#page/n99/mode/2up). The only traces of alien life had been found on Mars, left by a Martian civilization millions of years before. The story tells of the return of humanity's last starship, which had stumbled on the remains of a failed Martian colony far off in space.

Here's the part about the crewman who memorized the Bible:

> He tried to remember them, but there had been too many years and too many ships. On impulse, he knocked dust from the walls, scanning the names that had been left there against regulations—and left because he had countermanded those regulations. Surprisingly, he found the one he was seeking. Hugh Miffen, captain of the *Thirty-four*. Zeke remembered him now, a tow-headed boy with a ramrod back and the driving urge of divine inspiration in his eyes. And there had been "Preacher" Hook, who swore he was going to memorize the whole Bible in subspace. Only the two stood out now, over the long years.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> Miffen swung about, waving the three crewmen off. For the first time Zeke noticed that one of them had the flaming red hair that had always distinguished Preacher Hook.
>
> He lifted an eyebrow and Hook nodded, pulling out a worn Bible and making a circle with his thumb and finger. "All memorized," he said. But the grin on his face was uncertain, and the achievement no longer seemed to be important to him.

At the end of the story, Hook quotes a passage from *Ecclesiastes*.

For more excerpts from the story, see the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150610/lester-del-rey-short-story).